# How to use Oracle APEX page as bookmark?

Tags: oracle, url, oracle-apex, bookmarks

I want to save apex page as bookmark or share link with others, and after login to get that specific page.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: @pmdba put this as answer instead of comment so you’ll get points for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application must be configured to allow deep-linking to specific pages. If the application isn't configured for that, then you will always be taken to the login page and to the default application home page.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to set deep linking enabled for whole application?

Comment: Yes, you can find this setting in Shared Components -> Security Settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way to save page which has set page item?

Comment: Only if that item value is set in the URL. The application's security settings will determine how page items are stored. If the item value is specific to a session then it may not be possible.